# How to return all array with forEach with php?

Tags: php, arrays

How to return whole array with all info? Im trying to return info about users in array. I have 3 user with this parametrs but when i just return they show me only first of user. What wrong? Maybe need to return like forEach something by $user as value?

```
 function ___favorites($id_post) {
         global $wpdb;
         $users = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'users';
         $user_meta = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'usermeta';
         // делаем запрос
         $favorites = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM {$users} LEFT OUTER JOIN {$user_meta} ON {$user_meta}.user_id = {$users}.ID
         WHERE {$user_meta}.meta_key = 'fav_id' AND {$user_meta}.meta_value LIKE '%{$id_post}%'", ARRAY_A);
        return $favorites;
     }


function favorites_app($id_post) {
     $users = ___favorites($id_post);
    if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach($users as $value) {
        $user_data = get_userdata($value['ID']);
        $user_id =  get_user_by( 'login', $user_data->user_login);
    }
    return $users;
     } else {
     return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You never use `$user_id` in the foreach, is this normal ? You could add it in an array. Because each time in the foreach, `$user_id` is overwritten

Comment: which part is the problem? The favourites method will return all user IDs associated with the post. favourites_app just passes on the result of that query without changing it. Your foreach loop is essentially pointless because it doesn't do anything with the data it produces. Did you intend to create a new array and return that?

Comment: Sorry i just changing to this)

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for this i just changing to that, i just return empty data. And i rewrite for this) Sorry for stupid question!

```
     function ___favorites($id_post) {
         global $wpdb;
         $users = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'users';
         $user_meta = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'usermeta';
         // делаем запрос
         $favorites = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM {$users} LEFT OUTER JOIN {$user_meta} ON {$user_meta}.user_id = {$users}.ID
         WHERE {$user_meta}.meta_key = 'fav_id' AND {$user_meta}.meta_value LIKE '%{$id_post}%'", ARRAY_A);
        return $favorites;
     }



 function favorites_app($id_post)
        {
        if ( ! $users = ___favorites($id_post)) {
        return null;
        }

        $userData = [];

        foreach ($users as $user) {
        $data = get_userdata($user['ID']);
        $user_id =  get_user_by( 'login', $user_data->user_login);
        $userData[] = [
            'name' =>  $data->user_nicename,
            'id' => $data -> id,
            'avatar' => bp_core_fetch_avatar(array('item_id' => $user['ID'])),
            ];
        }

        return $userData;
}
```